# operator norm equivalence proof

Tags: real-analysis

Let $L: X \rightarrow Y$ be continuous linear map; $X, Y$ normed spaces(|| ||). Suppose  $ a = \sup_{x \in X, x \neq 0}\frac{||L(x)||}{||x||}, b = \sup_{||x|| \leq 1}||L(x)|| $. Consider equality $a = b$. To prove this equation we have to show that $ b \leq a $ and $a \leq b$. I know how to prove  $ b \leq a $, but i can't prove that $a \leq b$, because $ \frac{||L(x)||}{||x||} = \frac{1}{||x||}||L(x)|| $ But it doesn't mean,$  \frac{||L(x)||}{||x||} \leq b  $, since there can exist such $ x: ||x|| > 1 $ for which $ \frac{||L(x)||}{||x||} > b  $. Am i right? So is there any other proof?

Comment: This should help $b=\sup_{\|x\|=1}\|L(x)\|$ and for $x\neq 0$ and $y={x\over \|x\|}$ we have $\|y\|=1$

Comment: you mean other operator for norm

Comment: let's use c for this operator then i would have to show, that a = c and b = c but it seems to be more complicated :)